# Handle legend markers independently

Tags: python, matplotlib, text, legend

I have a plot with two types of lines: solid and dashed. Both solid and dashed lines represent the same quantity for different conditions and they have the same color.

Now, I'd like to add in an `ax.text()` the marker of the solid line to say that the solid line represents the quantity in that condition and another `ax.text()` with the marker of the dashed line to indicate the other condition. Somehow I mean something like this:

```
ax.text(0.9, 0.5, solid_marker + 'condition 1')
ax.text(0.9, 0.4, dashed_marker + 'condition 2')
```

Well, something like in this picture:

Example of what I want to do:

[image]

Does anybody knows how to do it? It is possible to use the symbols of the markers in random text in the plot?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your legend's spec is not standard. You need to create it manually. Here is a runnable code that can produce what you need.

```
#import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.lines as mlines
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Need to create legends manually

# First legend
#red_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='red', label='The red data')
black_line = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='black', linewidth=1.5, label=r'$Z_n$')
green_line = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='green', linewidth=1.5, label=r'$Z_p$')
red_line = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='red', linewidth=1.5, label=r'$Z_\pi$')

# Second legend
line_solid = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='black', linestyle='-', linewidth=1.5, label=r'$n_\beta = n_o$')
line_dashed = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='black', linestyle='--', linewidth=1.5, label=r'$n_\beta = n_o/2$')

first_legend = plt.legend(handles=[black_line, green_line, red_line], loc=1)
ax = plt.gca().add_artist(first_legend)
second_legend = plt.legend(handles=[line_solid, line_dashed], loc='best', \
                           bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 0.20, 0.5, 0.5)) #best upper-right
second_legend.set_frame_on(False)

plt.show()
```

The output plot:

[image: legend01]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @swatchai. I modified his answer to fit my code. So that I got:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.lines as mlines
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# my fig and my axes
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6))

# my plots
ax1.plot(temp, zn,  color=cycle[0], label=r'$z_n$')
ax1.plot(temp, zp,  color=cycle[1], label=r'$z_p$')
ax1.plot(temp, zpi, color=cycle[2], label=r'$z_\pi$')

# the other plots
ax1.plot(temp, zn2,  color=cycle[0], linestyle='--')
ax1.plot(temp, zp2,  color=cycle[1], linestyle='--')
ax1.plot(temp, zpi2, color=cycle[2], linestyle='--')

# Second legend 'imaginary' lines
line_solid = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='black', linestyle='-',    \
        linewidth=1.5, label=r'$n_b = n_0$')
line_dashed = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='black', linestyle='--',  \
        linewidth=1.5, label=r'$n_b = n_0/2$')

# original legend
leg1 = ax1.legend()

# set second legend (will remove first one)
leg2 = ax1.legend(handles=[line_solid, line_dashed], loc='best', \
            bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 0.20, 0.5, 0.6))

leg2.set_frame_on(False)    # remove legend frame
# manually add the first legend back
ax1.add_artist(leg1)
```

The output (notice that the above code is not runnable and it seem I cannot embed pictures yet):

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3X2T.png)

I actually wanted to avoid having to go through this step of creating new imaginary lines to assign a legend to them. I would have liked to know if it is possible to use the markers in a text too. But well, this at least solves my problem.

Thanks!